# Connecting 3 points on a 3d matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, 3d

I have 3 points on a 3D matrix and I want to connect them. So far, I can create a line going from 1 point to another, but I want to essentially create a triangle connecting 3 of the points.

Here's what I have so far

```
a = [1 1 2];
b = [4 2 9];
c = [5 3 6];

ab = b - a;

bc = c - b;

ca = a - c;


n = max(abs(ab)) + 1;
n1 = max(abs(bc)) + 1;
n2 = max(abs(ca)) + 1;

s = repmat(linspace(0, 1, n)', 1, 3);
for d = 1:3
    s(:, d) = s(:, d) * ab(d) + a(d);
end
s1 = repmat(linspace(0, 1, n1)', 1, 3);
for d1 = 1:3
    s1(:, d1) = s1(:, d1) * bc(d1) + b(d1);
end

s2 = repmat(linspace(0, 1, n2)', 1, 3);
for d2 = 1:3
    s2(:, d2) = s2(:, d2) * ca(d2) + c(d2);
end

s = round(s);
s1 = round(s1);
s2 = round(s2);

Z = 593; 
N = 512;
X = zeros(N, N, Z);
X1 = zeros(N, N, Z);
X2 = zeros(N, N, Z);
X(sub2ind(size(X), s(:, 1), s(:, 2), s(:, 3))) = 1;
X1(sub2ind(size(X1), s1(:, 1), s1(:, 2), s1(:, 3))) = 1;
X2(sub2ind(size(X2), s2(:, 1), s2(:, 2), s2(:, 3))) = 1;
clf

plot3(s(:, 1), s(:, 2), s(:, 3),1 ,s1(:, 1), s1(:, 2), s2(:, 3),2,s2(:, 1), s2(:, 2), s2(:, 3),3, 'r.-')
%plot3(s1(:, 1), s1(:, 2), s1(:, 3), 'r.-')
axis(N * [0 1 0 1 0 1])
grid on
```

Comment: why not use plot3 for each line?

Comment: you mean something like this? 

plot3(s(:, 1), s(:, 2), s(:, 3), 'r.-')

plot3(s1(:, 1), s1(:, 2), s1(:, 3), 'r.-')

plot3(s2(:, 1), s2(:, 2), s2(:, 3), 'r.-')

Comment: it ends up just being a straight line

Comment: `a2b = [a;b]; b2c = [b;c]; c2a = [c;a]; plot3(a2b(:1),a2b(:2),a2b(:3)); hold on; plot3(b2c(:1),b2c(:2),b2c(:3)); plot3(c2a(:1),c2a(:2),c2a(:3)); ` should give you a triangle with 3 lines, am i right? or the question is something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apologies if I misunderstood your questions, but I am having difficulties following the complexity of your code (*which doesn't run fully*) if the goal is only to join the 3 points in space.

To simply join the 3 points, the `plot3` function is a good choice, but it will not draw a line between the first and last points of your data set, so to force the last line, you can simply copy the coordinates of the first point at the end of your set so it will close the figure.

Note that I re-organised the coordinates data (from a variable for each point, to a variable for each coordinate axis)

```
a = [1 1 2]; %// I assumed these are [x y z] coordinate for point "a"
b = [4 2 9];
c = [5 3 6];

C = [a ; b ; c ] ;    %// place all coordinates in a single matrix
C(end+1,:) = C(1,:) ; %// replicate the first line in last position to close the triangle

x = C(:,1) ; %// place all "X" coordinate in a vector
y = C(:,2) ; %// then Y
z = C(:,3) ; %// then Z

hp = plot3(x,y,z) ;
```

Alternatively, if you want a coloured triangle, you can also use `patch` (*this function would close the figure by itself though, no need to add your copied point, but it doesn't hurt if you do*).

```
hpt = patch(x,y,z,'r') ;
```

[image: triangle]